# R mutate and dinamic variables

Tags: r, assign, mutate

I have a problem with dinamics variables in a mutate loop (I'm sooo new in R).
I have a dataframe with the data and I have to make some operations with three cells of each line and the same cells from the above line.
The cells names are tonext1, left1 and total_tonext1 (tonext2, left2, etc...)
And those final vars have to be added to a new DF ("newdf")

The first 3 columns are done yet, because they are calculated by another way, but next ones are calculated in the same way

I've tried with and without "eval()" (the commented line is an example) and many other things witout success.
And "total_tonext(i)" value is the cumulative sum until that element.

How do you think it must be done?

Thanks a lot and a good day to you all!!

```
for(i in 2:4){
  assign("actual_tonext", paste0("tonext", i))
  assign("above_tonext", paste0("tonext", i-1))
  assign("actual_left", paste0("left", i))
  assign("above_left", paste0("left", i-1))
  assign("total_tonext", paste0("total_tonext", i))
  assign("variable", paste0("value", i))
  
  newdf = final_df %>%
   mutate(
     #eval(actual_tonext) = lag(eval(above_tonext)) + lag(eval(above_left)) - eval(above_left),
     actual_tonext = lag(above_tonext) + lag(above_left) - above_left,
     actual_left = variable - actual_tonext,
     total_tonext = cumsum(replace_na(actual_tonext, 0))
   )
}
```

Without "assign" (to watch it clear), the first step of for loop (i = 2):

```
newdf = final_df %>%
  mutate(
    tonext2 = lag(tonext1) + lag(left1) - left1,
    left2 = value2 - tonext2,
    total_tonext2 = cumsum(replace_na(tonext2, 0)),
  )
```

This is the dataframe I have. Columns "value3, 4 and 5" are hidden to make it clear.
The columns "tonext2", "left2" and "total_tonext2" are the ones I want to have (and 3, 4...)
For example,the "186" value of "tonext2" is 11+899-724

| "princ" | "value1" | "value2" | "tonext1" | "left1" | "total_tonext1" | "tonext2" | "left2" | "total_tonext2" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | 42 | NA | NA | NA | 0 | NA | NA | 0 |
| 45 | 45 | 0 | 3 | 42 | 3 | NA | NA | 0 |
| 45 | 45 | 0 | 0 | 45 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 45 | 45 | 0 | 0 | 45 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 221 | 221 | 0 | 176 | 45 | 179 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 307 | 307 | 0 | 86 | 221 | 265 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 438 | 438 | 0 | 131 | 307 | 39 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 438 | 438 | 0 | 0 | 438 | 396 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 475 | 475 | 0 | 37 | 438 | 433 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 899 | 899 | 0 | 424 | 475 | 85 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 910 | 910 | 0 | **11** | **899** | 868 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 918 | 732 | 187 | 8 | **724** | 876 | **186** | 1 | 186 |
| 918 | 732 | 187 | 0 | 732 | 876 | 0 | 187 | 186 |
| 1018 | 829 | 190 | 100 | 729 | 976 | 3 | 187 | 189 |
| 1227 | 102 | 207 | 209 | 812 | 1185 | 17 | 190 | 206 |
| 1234 | 102 | 206 | 7 | 1021 | 1192 | 0 | 206 | 206 |
| 1387 | 117 | 208 | 153 | 1026 | 1345 | 2 | 206 | 208 |
| 2495 | 219 | 298 | 1108 | 1083 | 2453 | 96 | 202 | 304 |
| 2495 | 219 | 298 | 0 | 2191 | 2453 | 0 | 298 | 304 |
| 2495 | 218 | 302 | 0 | 2186 | 2453 | 5 | 297 | 309 |
| 2512 | 220 | 302 | 17 | 2186 | 2470 | 0 | 302 | 309 |

Comment: Here's some general advice that will make your code simpler and easier to read: forget that `assign` and `eval` exist. You categorically do not need them here (or basically anywhere), and they make your code needlessly more complicated.

Comment: To add to @KonradRudolph's comment - with which I completely agree: the fundamental issue here is that your data frame is not [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) because information you need to perform your calculation is not available from the values it contains: you need information from the column *names*, not the column *values*.  Pivot your data to long format (and introduce an `Index` column to hold the suffix values in your column names), and then use `group_by()` and `lag()` in your calculations.